# Retrieve a number value from a cell corresponding to the same row but different column of another cell (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets

I use LARGE to find the (cell with the) largest number in column G.  How do I retrieve the number from the same ROW as in G but in column F (so I can add them together)?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to retrieve the corresponding value or retrieve the sum of the two values?

In order to retrieve just the corresponding value you need to use a VLOOKUP. But, because you cannot return a negative column value such as column F by searching Column G, you have to use an in-formula array to rearrange the columns within the calculation. Here is the formula:

`=ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(large(G2:G,1),{G2:G,F2:F},2, FALSE))`

This is assuming that row 1 is a header row.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=SUM(INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(LARGE(G2:G, 1), G2:F, {1,2}, ))))
```

or:

```
=SUM(INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(MAX(G2:G, G2:F, {1,2}, ))))
```